# Continuous embedding of the fractional space $H^{\frac12}(\mathbb R)$ into $L^q(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

My question is about the Theorem 6.5 in the  [Hitchhiker's guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345).

Consider the case $n=1$ and $p=2$. Theorem 6.5 states that if $s<\frac12$, then $H^s(\mathbb R)$ is continuously embedded in $L^q(\mathbb R)$ for any $q\in [2, 2^*_s]$, where $2^*_s$ is the fractional Sobolev exponent.

What happens when $s=\frac12$? Does the continuous embedding hold anyway?

Possibly this result can not be deduced by Theorem 6.5, but maybe there is another way to include the case $s=\frac12$ in the embedding result (at least in my case of interest in which $n=1$ and $p=2$.

If it is the case, how one can prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $s=1/2$, we have that $H^s(\mathbb R) \hookrightarrow L^q(\mathbb R)$ for all $2\leq q<+\infty$ and the embedding fails for $q=+\infty$. All the proofs and detailing discussion can be found in Chapter 2 of “A first course in fractional Sobolev spaces” by Giovanni Leoni.

Comment: JackT, thanks for the detailed answer. I would like to know whether $H^{\frac12}(\mathbb R)$ is precompact in $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb R)$ for $p\in [1, 2^*_s)$. This should be true for $s\in (0, 1/2)$ (again by the Hitchhiker's guide), but I am interested in extending this result to the case $s=1/2$. Do you have an answer for this case as well? If you prefer, I can post a new question.